# 2-generated p-groups with generators of order p

Tags: probability, group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated, p-groups

Let $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ be a finite $p$-group such that $a^p=b^p=1$. Is there any result about the size of the set of $p$-elements $\Omega(G):=\{g\in G\mid g^p=1\}$? In particular, I'm interested in the fraction $|\Omega(G)|/|G|$.

Edit: I was exactly wondering about if the fraction $|Ω(G)|/|G|$
could be done arbitrarily small in this class of groups. I'm not able to find a reference to this (or conversely a theorem that states the existence of a positive lower bound $c$).

Comment: I was exactly wondering about if the fraction $|\Omega(G)|/|G|$ could be done arbitrarily small in this class of groups. I'm not able to find a reference to this (or conversely a theorem that states the existance of a positive lower bound $c$).

Comment: Sorry, I have deleted my comment - the examples I had in mi nd don't work.

Comment: If the group has class $c\lt p$, then the group is regularr, and the set of elements of exponent $p$ forms a subgroup; since the subgroup would contain the generators of the group, it follows that $G$ itself has exponent $p$, so $\Omega_1(G)=G$ in this case. The same holds if the group has order at most $p^p$, since it will be regular as well.

Comment: Thank you both!

Comment: Computer experiments that I have done with primes $3,5,7$  suggest strongly that there is no lower bound on $|\Omega(G)/G|$ and it approaches zero as the nilpotency class increases. I don't know how to go about proving it. You could try asking on mathoverflow.